# unable to add <br /> in div

Tags: jquery, html, line-breaks

I am trying to add multiple divs at run time using jQuery. I want to add 3 divs which are of same class and then append line break so when user clicks on "Add boxes" button again, i can display 3 more divs in the next line.

Here is the jsFiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/WjFCf/3/

As you can see in the jsFiddle, it does almost everything but doesnt add line break after 3rd div. So when user clicks the button again, it just adds more divs in the same line.

Can someone please help me to get this right?

Comment: `Inspect Element` clearly shows the line break... it's a CSS problem.

Comment: Do you want them to stay in lines of three regardless of how narrow the window is?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes. Thats the intention.

Comment: @Asdfg that solutions that rely on `clear` or `display` on their own won't achieve that - they'll wrap if the screen gets to narrow.  The only solution is to put them in a fixed width container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to `clear` it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WjFCf/4/

Notice the CSS change.

Answer (score 1):

Your line break is being added, the problem is `float: left` on the boxes. If you change that to `display: inline-block` you will get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your boxes into a container of (sufficient) fixed width it will ensure that they stay grouped in threes correctly.

As it stands, if the window gets too small the "excess" divs will drop onto the next line.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ZbPxG/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have the next row of boxes have the `clear:both` property so that they will be under the floated boxes above.

http://jsfiddle.net/WjFCf/5/

Answer (score 1):

When I add this code to yours, it works well:

```css
#boxes{
   width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: yes, that works because it ensures that there's never room for more than three boxes horizontally, so the 4th one will _always_ flow down to the line below.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` will not push div's down effectively on it's own.

Using the [clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) property will be much more effective. This tells the browser to stop paying attention to the previous float left (or right), and start a new float area.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/CTF8E/)